# Does datastage server jobs needs configuration file?

Tags: datastage

Parallel jobs need configuration file in DataStage, what about server jobs? Normally server jobs runs in sequential mode only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplistically put Configuration file binds code to the hardware on which the code should execute, hence there is always a default config file (unless explicitly specified) that is used when a job runs. So even server jobs need a CPU to get executed hence the config file.

check this one out if it helps:
http://mydatastage-notes.blogspot.com.au/2013/04/configuration-file.html

IBM docs have there own version which you can look up...

Answer (score 0):

DataStage Server jobs don't need any configuration file defined to run. Server jobs are run sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Server jobs do not require a configuration file. They run on the machine on which the DSEngine software is installed, usually referred to as the Engine Tier.